# The argument type 'double' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PointLatLng'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-fragments

This is my code

```
PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
List<PointLatLng> pointsList =
await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
    Const.google_map_api_key,
    _trackingModel.driverLat,
    _trackingModel.driverLng,
    _trackingModel.customerLat,
    _trackingModel.customerLng);
```

> A value of type 'PolylineResult' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not retrieving the list from the results but directly feeding in the results object. Try extracting the list of points by doing this-

```
List<PointLatLng> pointsList =
(await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
    Const.google_map_api_key,
    _trackingModel.driverLat,
    _trackingModel.driverLng,
    _trackingModel.customerLat,
    _trackingModel.customerLng)).points;
```

Also please provide more details about the problem like which package you are using so that it helps others to debug it better.